# Access a single cell / subsetted column of a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

How can I access just a single cell in a `data.table` in the way as I could for a `data.frame`:

```
mdf <- data.frame(a = c("A", "B", "C"), b = rnorm(3), c = 1:3)
mdf[ mdf$a == "B", "c" ]
[1] 2
```

Doing the analogue on a `data.table` a data.table is returned including the key column(s):

```
mdt <- data.table( mdf, key = "a" )
mdt[ "B", c ]
   a c
1: B 2

mdt[ "B", c ][ , c]
[1] 2
```

Did I miss a parameter or does it has to be done as in the last line?

Comment: FWIW `mdt['B', c]` now returns a vector as you initially expected. Not sure how long ago this changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either of these will avoid repeating the c but are not as efficient since they involve computing the first [] as well as the final answer:

```
> mdt[ "B", ][["c"]]
[1] 2
> mdt[ "B", ][, c]
[1] 2
```

Comment: Those commas after "B" are not needed, I guess. And a third way, along the same lines: `mdt["B"]$c`.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of `data.table` make this easier

```
mdt[ "B", c]
# [1] 2
```

---

Original answer was returning a `data.table` like:

```
mdt['B', 'c']
#        c
# 1:     2
```

Comment: good point, but then the return value will be still a one-cell `data.table`.